# jQuery require_from_group if a form field is filled/selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a page which allows people to input details of up to five Referrals which are non-compulsory. Each group of referral is contained within its own `div`.

When any one of the fields is filled/selected, I need to check that all the other fields and at least one contact number within the same `div` are filled as well. If no field is filled/selected, the form should pass through successfully.

I am stuck at this for the longest as I only managed to use `require_from_group` for the contact numbers which checks for at least one contact number filled, but it doesn't fulfill what I require.

HTML code for form fields

```
<div id="Referral1" class="parentClass">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="control-label col-md-12" style="color: #6d0017;"><strong>My Referral: </strong></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Salutation</div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <select type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_1_Salutation">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                <option value="Mdm">Mdm</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="error-msg"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Name</div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_1_Name" value="" maxlength="50">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="error-msg"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="control-label col-md-4 required-atleastone" style="padding-right:0;">Contact Number (Mobile)</div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="oneormore form-control" name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile" value="" maxlength="20">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="error-msg"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="control-label col-md-4 required-atleastone" style="padding-right:0;">Contact Number (Home)</div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="oneormore form-control" name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Home" value="" maxlength="20">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="error-msg"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="control-label col-md-4 required-atleastone" style="padding-right:0;">Contact Number (Office)</div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="oneormore form-control" name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Office" value="" maxlength="20">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="error-msg"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Email Address</div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_1_Email" value="" maxlength="50">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="error-msg"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Best Time to Call
            <span class="popovers" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Our office hours are from 8.45 am to 6.00 pm, Monday to Friday (except public holidays). If you send this after office hours, we will respond to you the next working day."><i class="fa fa-info-circle text-red"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <select type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                <option value="9am_to_12pm">9am - 12 pm</option>
                <option value="12pm_to_2pm">12pm - 2pm</option>
                <option value="2pm_to_4pm">2pm - 4pm</option>
                <option value="4pm_to_6pm">4pm - 6pm</option>
                <option value="Anytime">Anytime</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="error-msg"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery function which currently checks that at least one contact number is needed to be filled

```
var initCustomerReferralFormComponents = function() {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group_contact", function (value, element, options) {
        var validator = this;
        var minRequired = options[0];
        var selector = options[1];
        var validOrNot = jQuery(selector, element.form).filter(function () {
            return validator.elementValue(this);
        }).length >= minRequired;

        // remove all events in namespace upload

        jQuery(selector, element.form).off('.require_from_group_contact');

        if (this.settings.onkeyup) {
            jQuery(selector, element.form).on({
                'keyup.require_from_group_contact': function (e) {
                    jQuery(selector, element.form).valid();
                }
            });
        }
        if (this.settings.onfocusin) {
            jQuery(selector, element.form).on({
                'focusin.require_from_group_contact': function (e) {
                    jQuery(selector, element.form).valid();
                }
            });
        }
        if (this.settings.click) {
            jQuery(selector, element.form).on({
                'click.require_from_group_contact': function (e) {
                    jQuery(selector, element.form).valid();
                }
            });
        }
        if (this.settings.onkeyup) {
            jQuery(selector, element.form).on({
                'keyup.require_from_group_contact': function (e) {
                    jQuery(selector, element.form).valid();
                }
            });
        }
        return validOrNot;
    }, "Fill in all fields.");

    $("#customer_referral").validate({  
        rules: {
            Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile: {
                require_from_group_contact: [1, ".oneormore"]
            },
            Referral_1_Contact_Number_Home: {
                require_from_group_contact: [1, ".oneormore"]
            },
            Referral_1_Contact_Number_Office: {
                require_from_group_contact: [1, ".oneormore"]
            }
        },
        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
             $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.error-msg').text(error.text());
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success')
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            console.log('form submit');
            form.submit();
        }
     });
 }
```

Comment: I rolled back the edits to the original because the numerous code re-formats added three stray `</div>` tags and numerous improper indentations.  Please be more careful when cleaning up the code from others' questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very tedious...

You create a conditional function to see if any of the other four fields are filled out and then apply the parameters of the `require_from_group` rule using a function.

Do the same for the other fields but instead using the `required` rule.

Adjust accordingly.

```
rules: { 
    Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile: {
        require_from_group: function(element) {
            if ($('[name="Referral_1_Salutation"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Name"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Email"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call"]').is(':filled')) {
                return [1, ".oneormore"];
            } else {
                return [0, ".oneormore"];
            }
        }
    },
    ....
    // repeat same for remaining contact numbers
    ....

    Referral_1_Salutation: {
        required: function(element) {
            return ($('[name="Referral_1_Name"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Email"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Home"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Office"]').is(':filled'));
        }
    },
    ....
    // repeat same for remaining other fields
    ....
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/cd5gy73u/**

---

**EDIT**:

Much of the code could be replaced with the `skip_or_fill_minimum` rule:

http://jsfiddle.net/yo2vjwus/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I really appreciate it! I hope this helps other people who are facing the same issue as me as I haven't been able to find similar questions online. I tried writing a new function for it, but wasn't successful as I am still a novice at jquery.