# Looping of rules Jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-validate

I have a form which allows people to refer up to 5 people. Within the form, if referral 1's name is filled, the jquery code below checks and prompts the user to fill in the other form fields related to referral 1.

I am wondering is it possible to create a loop which does the checking 5x instead of copying and pasting the below code for each set of referral?

```
$("#customer_referral").validate({  

        rules: {

           Referral_1_Salutation: {
                required: function(element) {
                 if($('[name="Referral_1_Name"]').is(':filled')||$('[name="Referral_1_Email"]').is(':filled')||$('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Home"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Office"]').is(':filled')||($('[name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0)){
                     return true;                            
                 } else {                    
                     return false;
                 } 
                }           
            },

           Referral_1_Name: {
                required: function(element) {
                 if(($('[name="Referral_1_Salutation"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0) || $('[name="Referral_1_Email"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Home"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Office"]').is(':filled')||($('[name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0)){
                     return true;                            
                 } else {                    
                     return false;
                 } 
                }                   
            },  
           Referral_1_Email: {
                required: function(element) {
                 if(($('[name="Referral_1_Salutation"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0) || $('[name="Referral_1_Name"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Home"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Office"]').is(':filled')||($('[name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0)){
                     return true;                            
                 } else {                    
                     return false;
                 } 
                }                   
            },  

           Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call: {
                required: function(element) {
                 if(($('[name="Referral_1_Salutation"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0) || $('[name="Referral_1_Name"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Email"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Home"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Office"]').is(':filled')){
                     return true;                            
                 } else {                    
                     return false;
                 } 
                }                   
            },                                                  

        //Check if any one of the contact number is filled
        Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile: {
            require_from_group_contact: function(element) {
                if (($('[name="Referral_1_Salutation"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0) || $('[name="Referral_1_Name"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Email"]').is(':filled') || ($('[name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0)) {
                    return [1, ".oneormore"];
                } else {
                    return [0, ".oneormore"];
                }
            }
        },

        Referral_1_Contact_Number_Home: {
            require_from_group_contact: function(element) {
                if (($('[name="Referral_1_Salutation"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0) || $('[name="Referral_1_Name"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Email"]').is(':filled') || ($('[name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0)) {
                    return [1, ".oneormore"];
                } else {
                    return [0, ".oneormore"];
                }
            }
        },
        Referral_1_Contact_Number_Office: {
            require_from_group_contact: function(element) {
                if (($('[name="Referral_1_Salutation"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0) || $('[name="Referral_1_Name"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Email"]').is(':filled') || ($('[name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0)) {
                    return [1, ".oneormore"];
                } else {
                    return [0, ".oneormore"];
                }
            }
        }
        //End of check if any one of the contact number is filled                                                                   

        },
 });
```

Comment: As a side note, try using the [require from group](https://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/) validator to cut down on your repeated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules can also be applied via [the `.rules()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/), which gives you the ability to use jQuery selectors that target things more generically.  So when the selector targets multiple items, you can use a jQuery `.each()` to loop through them all.

```
$('.myfields').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        // other rules
    });
});
```

---

On a side-note...

```
required: function(element) {                  
    if ($('[name="Referral_1_Name"]').is(':filled')||$('[name="Referral_1_Email"]').is(':filled')||$('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Home"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Office"]').is(':filled')||($('[name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0)) {
        return true;                            
    } else {                    
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Since you're returning a boolean based on a boolean condition, your function could be greatly simplified by just returning the result of the conditional...

```
required: function(element) {                    
    return ($('[name="Referral_1_Name"]').is(':filled')||$('[name="Referral_1_Email"]').is(':filled')||$('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Mobile"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Home"]').is(':filled') || $('[name="Referral_1_Contact_Number_Office"]').is(':filled')||($('[name="Referral_1_Best_Time_To_Call"]').prop("selectedIndex")!=0));
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

Firstly, everything needs to be re-worked to be more generic.  I took [the code from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37478736/594235) and reworked it a bit to get something more generic.  Instead of conditionally looking at every field, I've employed the `skip_or_fill_minimum` rule to replace the `required` rule.

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yo2vjwus/

Now that we have a working model that is generic enough, we can use the `.rules()` method to apply these rules to multiple fields at once.

```
$('[name^=Referral_1_]:not("[name^=Referral_1_Contact]")').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        skip_or_fill_minimum: [4, '[name^=Referral_1_]:not("[name^=Referral_1_Contact]")']
    });
});

$('[name^="Referral_1_Contact"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        require_from_group: function(element) {
            if ($('[name="Referral_1_Salutation"]').is(':filled')) {
                return [1, '[name^=Referral_1_Contact]'];
            } else {
                return [0, '[name^=Referral_1_Contact]'];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yo2vjwus/1/

As far as the remaining four sets of fields, you will have to duplicate this code OR make it even more generic and put everything inside of another jQuery `.each()`.

```
var i = 1;

$('[id^="Referral"]').each(function() {

    $('[name^=Referral_' + i + '_]:not("[name^=Referral_' + i + '_Contact]")').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [4, '[name^=Referral_' + i + '_]:not("[name^=Referral_' + i + '_Contact]")']
        });
    });

    $('[name^="Referral_' + i + '_Contact"]').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            require_from_group: function(element) {
                if ($(element).parents('.parentClass').find('[name$="_Salutation"]').is(':filled')) {
                    return [1, '[name^="Referral_' + i + '_Contact"]'];
                } else {
                    return [0, '[name^="Referral_' + i + '_Contact"]'];
                }
            }
        });
    });

    i++;

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yo2vjwus/2/**

Comment: I really have no idea how to incorporate the rules and require_from_group that you have stated above. Can you please give a more in depth example?

Comment: @user558085, see my edited answer.  However, keep in mind that you simply asked how to apply the rules using a loop.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. However I think the $('[name^="Referral_' + i + '_Contact"]').each function was not executed as the 3 contact numbers were not prompted to be filled when Salutation was selected.

Comment: @user558085, although the message does not show immediately, hit the submit button again to see that all rules are indeed in force.  This is a shortcoming of using the `.rules()` method to add conditional rules.  Please note that considerable time was spent to *show you* how this could be done.  If you're not fully satisfied with the requested example, feel free to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi Sparky, yes i understand the effort and appreciate it. Was just wondering why it didn't work as I didn't know the shortcoming of .rules() method. So now i understand after your explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @user558085, I wish I could explain it better, and I'll have to look at the developer's Github page to see if this issue has been reported.  If it's critical, you may simply have to declare the conditional rules within `.validate()`.

Comment: I think it's a bit complicated for me to comprehend. Seems like the original solution you have provided in the other question I've asked is  more straight forward although tedious. Once again, thanks for taking time to answer both of my questions. :)